# Simple thermodynamics basics - can internal energy be calculated?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy

Well this got me stumbled, because I've been wondering what the "question" is. One of the example examns got the following question (strangely there are no supplied solution books):

> A $0.2 {\rm m^3}$  thermally insulated rigid container is divided into two
> equal volumes by only a thin membrane. Initially, one of these
> chambers is filled with air at a pressure of $700\, {\rm kPa}$ and $37 \, {\rm C}$ while
> the other chamber is evacuated.
>
> $C_p = 1.005 \frac{{\rm kJ}}{{\rm kg \cdot K}}\,$ and $\, C_v =0.721 \frac{{\rm kJ}}{{\rm kg \cdot K}}$

Now the questions:

> a)    Determine the change in internal energy of the air when the membrane is ruptured.
> b)    Determine the final air pressure in the container

Is this now a really silly question or am I missing something important? Cause isn't the internal energy an intrinsic property that has to be looked up/ experimentally determined?

And for the second problem, as there can be no energy transfer the internal energy also has to stay the same - so the temperature doesn't change and the pressure simply halves. ($PV = {\rm constant}$). Or am I missing something?

Comment: In [Joule expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_expansion), (irreversible process) internal energy is conserved. For a reversible process, it is an [isentropic process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isentropic). For a [Joule-Thomson expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect), enthalpy is conserved.

Comment: @Trimok Well how could I determine what the actual process is, I can rule out an isentropic process I guess. But the other two seem very similar though.

Comment: It looks like a [Joule Expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_expansion), so, for the first question, you would be right ; the internal energy is conserved. For the second question, if we consider air at 700kPa as an ideal gas, then the internal energy does depends only on temperature, so the temperature is conserved, and the relation $pV$= Constant is correct. However, if you do not consider air as an ideal gas, then the temperature is not conserved, then the relation $pV$= Constant is not correct. However, the questions seem very odd (at least the first) if it is a Joule expansion !!

Comment: What you can do is to answer the questions for both cases -[Joule expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_expansion) - and [Joule-Thomson expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect)

Answer (score 3):

The internal energy of an ideal gas can only change if heat is added or removed from the system, or if the system does some work. Neither is the case in this example so the change in internal energy is zero.

The final pressure is, as you say, just half the initial pressure.

I'm not sure why they give you the specific heats, but you can use them to work out how ideal your gas is. The specific heats of an ideal diatomic gas should be 2.5 and 3.5 joules/mole/R, and converting the specific heats you're given to J/mole/R (assuming an average $M_w$ of 28.8 for air) gives 2.50 and 3.48 to two SF. So approximating the air as an ideal gas seems entirely justified.

**Response to comment:**

You're given $C_v$ = 721 J/kg/K. The average molecular weight of air is 28.8 (assuming 20% oxygen and 80% nitrogen) so one mole is 0.0288kg. Multiplying by 0.0288 to convert to moles gives $C_v$ = 20.76 J/mole/K. Now divide by the molar gas constant, $R$ = 8.314 J/mole/K, to get $C_v$ = 2.50 (to 2 significant figures). Exactly the same calculation gives 3.48 for $C_p$.

Comment: How would you do this conversion? That seems the missing link I'm missing? $C_p = C_v + R$? But then R is also a dependent variable?

Answer (score 1):

The way the question is worded "when the membrane is ruptured" sounds like a Joule expansion.  The answer depends (sort of) on what class this is for.  Based on the title of your question, it sounds to me that this exam is for *just a basic thermodynamics course* in which case this is likely just a "trick" question.

So it's just a classic Joule expansion, no change in internal energy, and the pressure is halved (to 350 kPA).  Neither heat capacity is relevant because the process is not reversible, not at equilibrium, and neither the volume nor pressure is constant.  All that added information is just to try to throw you off, to see if you really understand what's going on.  That's my take on this (unless I'm missing something). HTH.

Answer (score -4):

This is a case of adiabatic expansion. So change in internal energy is work done by the gas or system.

$dU=-dW=-\dfrac{P_iV_i-P_fV_f}{\gamma -1}\tag*{}$

where $\gamma =C_p/C_v$

Also, change in internal energy is given by,

$\Delta U=mC_v(T_f-T_i)\tag*{}$

where, $T_f=T_i\left(\dfrac{V_i}{V_f}\right)^{\gamma -1}$ and, $m=\dfrac{PV}{RT}M$

$dU=-42,650$ joules

Now final air pressure can be given by,

$P_iV_i^\gamma =P_fV_f^\gamma \implies P_f=266.4$ kPa

Above many answers and comments considered it as irreversible adaibatic case, but this is not. Instead of membrane if piston is placed and which moves quickly upto double the volume of the container. Now piston can be pushed back to same volume and if heat is not exchanged then it can gain its initial state.

The work done on the system to move back to its initial position is equal to work done by the system or gas during expansion. Thus by calculating external work, we can find the change in internal energy during expansion.

Edit: This is to show that there is change in internal energy in OP's question. Calculation from online calculator is pasted.
[image: https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/thermodynamic-processes]

**TWO DOWNVOTES FOR CORRECT ANSWER, NOT FIRST TIME.NOW THREE**

Comment: This is (irreversible) expansion into a vacuum. The gas doesn't do any work as it expands to fill the remaining part of the container.

Comment: Volume of gas changes, thus this is equivalent to work done. One can't utilize it's another question. Also, change in internal energy was not derived by work done in case.

Comment: See [any introductory resource](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Book%3A_Thermodynamics_and_Chemical_Equilibrium_(Ellgen)/07%3A_State_Functions_and_The_First_Law/7.17%3A_Free_Expansion_of_a_Gas) which describes free expansion (in particular, the last equation). There is no work done by the gas and no heat transferred through the container, so the internal energy does not change (unless you model air as a non-ideal gas, which is clearly beyond the scope of the OP).

Comment: $PdV$ is work done. And there is change in internal energy which is not possible without work, that is why it comes out negative. When volume expansion that lowers pressure and that temperature. So how is internal energy not change, when pressure, volume and temperature change.

Comment: $P dV$ is the work done **when the gas expands against an external pressure $P$**.  In this case, the gas is not expanding against *any* external pressure - it is expanding into vacuum. No heat is added and no work is done. The pressure decreases and the volume increases, but the temperature and internal energy remain constant, while the entropy increases. My previous comment contains a link to an online chemistry textbook which you may find useful.

Comment: @NeilLibertine Why are you posting an incorrect answer to a question that is almost ten years old?

Comment: @NeilLibertine The empty part of the container is at zero pressure, because it's **empty**. But I'm not going to sit here and argue with you. I've explained why you are wrong, the link I posted explains why you are wrong, the correct answers to this question posted by John Rennie and Daniel Goldfarb almost ten years ago explains why you are wrong. Best of luck with your studies.

Comment: @J.Murray Who says that work done is against the external pressure. A gas can work done upto the external pressure only. After that internal and external pressure equate. But in calculation take value of internal pressure. In isothermal, pressure decreses but taken as constant.

Comment: Have you read about [joule expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_expansion) in your classes yet? This is precisely the situation described in the OP: "*Initially, one of these chambers is filled with air at a pressure of 700kPa and 37C while the other chamber is evacuated [...] Determine the change in internal energy of the air when the membrane is ruptured.*"

Comment: So you have read more about thermodynamics. So this joule expansion process comes under which constant heat, constant volume, constant pressure or constant temperature process. In PV doagram, are you calculating external pressure for work done, hmm.

Comment: Answer given by John Rennie also had change in pressure, half of initial. So how temperature remain same if pressure changes. Still you think internal energy remain constant.

Comment: @Neil Libertine. Think about it. The gas is the only body that hold energy inside of the container. The walls of the container are rigid (=no work can be done against them) and thermally insulated (=no energy can get through). Then how could the internal energy of the gas (=total energy inside of the container) change if the only thing done opening a hole in the beginning?

Comment: @NeilLibertine Joule expansion cannot be represented as a curve on a PV diagram because it is not a quasistatic process; during the expansion, the gas does not *have* a well-defined pressure or volume.  When the gas has fully expanded to fill the other half of the container, the new equilibrium pressure will be half the initial pressure, while the volume will be double the initial volume. There is no heat transferred to the gas, and since the gas does not do any work (e.g. by pushing a piston outward), the internal energy (and therefore temperature) of the ideal gas remains constant.

Comment: What you believe that there is no change in internal energy, thus or because there is no change in temperature. But pressure changes from relation, $PV^{\gamma}=constant$. So there must be change in temperature. Does 1 tonne and 2 tonne of AC cools a same room equally and what if room is opens frequently or crowded. Here pressure of cold gas, affect temperature of a room.

Comment: Neil, this will be my last response. The expression $PV^\gamma=const$ holds for a **reversible, adiabatic process**. Joule expansion is **not reversible**. If you are a student, I suggest you ask an instructor or somebody you are willing to listen to to explain this, since obviously you think that none of us know what we're talking about. If you are not a student, please search any introductory textbook (such as the one I linked) for Joule expansion or "free expansion of a gas".

Comment: I seen joule expansion which is special case of adiabatic expansion. And there is one question regarding that on this forum in which some author made argument that as volume of both chambers remain same, so there is no work done. Thus to make temperature look constant. I have one question, if weight of piston and its head is more then work done is more or less. If less, then it means work done depends upon volume expansion and pressure is pressure of gas. Again, if pressure changes, then how temperature or internal energy remain same.